# How to retain the selected items in list view when returning to an activity

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I made a List View, when i select some items on list (the selection I made it of green color and deselection i made it of white) move the scroll bar down and go up again i loose the selections i made. how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Please add essential parts of your code to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

its not selection, its focus . focused item will keep changing along with scrolling . if you want to override focused behavior set a background to listView and read about clearCachehint .